# unwanted string coming with all event title in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

i am using fullcalendar and its working fine.i got the tutorial from
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

but here some unwanted string like "12a" is coming with all event title.i want to remove this unwanted name. i checked in both css and js file but i am unable to find where it is included.

anyone help me to remove this "12a" string from all event name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To delete "12a", add `displayEventTime: false`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title:  'My Event',
            start:  '2010-01-01T14:30:00',
            allDay: false
        }
        // other events here...
    ],
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock、
    displayEventTime: false,
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Hiding the css class `fc-time` has unintended ramifications on other views, especially the timeGridDay view. For example, it will hide the time navigation on the left-hand side of the screen and users will see events dangling in the middle of the UI with no indication of when they start or end.

Answer (score 11):

This "12a" represents the start time of your event, i.e. "12 am".
You can change the formatting in the calendar options:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title:  'My Event',
            start:  '2010-01-01T14:30:00',
            allDay: false
        }
        // other events here...
    ],
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
});
```

Source: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/

If you want to hide the start time from your event, simply add this to your CSS:

```
.fc-time{
   display : none;
}
```

Comment: thanks.... i did only one change .... i used like this                                            timeFormat: ' '    because in some time the updation in css file is not working for me if we gave  timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'   then it will again shows the time so i used    timeFormat: ' '

Comment: From now on, the class for time label is, `c-event-time`

Answer (score 0):

If we use `displayEventTime: false` then it will remove all the time stamp from that event,
but if you wat the start time but not the other/end time then write CSS.

**Class name as per the latest version.**

```
.fc-event-end   .fc-event-time{
  
        display: none;

}
```